# Allow us to swipe right to open the left menu on iOS

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

When one wants to switch to another community or to check their profile etc, they want to open the menu that's accessible by clicking the button in the upper-left corner.

[image: screenshot]

Sometimes it's really inconvenient to tap this button, which is also difficult to reach for (especially for iPhone 6/6+ etc users).

When some question is clicked on and shown on the screen, one can simply swipe right to go back (actually, to go to the page that's situated to the left of the page with this question).

Moreover, when in the left menu, one can swipe left to go back to the questions feed or to the profile stats etc.

Why cannot we swipe right to access the left menu then? I'm proposing to add this feature to the iOS app.

Comment: On an iPhone 6 and higher, you can double-tap the home button, this will 'lower' the screen to a more manageable size for your fingers.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I know, and that's what I'm actually doing, but it's still very inconvenient since after I've swiped away from a question I wanna swipe once more and get to the menu. Won't a simple swipe be better than all this double-tapping business?

Comment: You may want to clarify that it should be an edge swipe, to allow for the possibility of a tableViewCell being right-swiped to bring up options.

Comment: You may want to see if this can get migrated to MSE, while it is perfectly acceptable to ask here, it does affect the whole Stack Exchange network instead of just Stack Overflow so you may get more input On Meta Meta.

Comment: @TinyGiant, that should be awesome, but I don't know anything about migrating questions. As far as I know this could be done by users with special privileges. I don't have enough rep to do it. Should I ask someone to do it?

Comment: @TinyGiant, okay, I'll try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be added in the next build.

The menu will open if a pan gesture is initiated:

- inside the navigation bar on *any* screen.
- outside the navigation bar AND at the left edge of the screen AND on a root screen (one with a menu button instead of a back button).

Comment: Great news! That should really make the SE app easier to use. Thanks.